# Can excel macro run on browser?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to run a macro on web browser? I can open an excel in a browser but i am not sure if macro can run with it. And also, how am I going to enable it automatically within a browser?

Comment: what do you mean when you say you can open an excel in a browser? Excel is an executable, and this is the first time I hear someone say they've opened Excel in a browser? Can you explain how are you opening your *Excel in browser*?

Comment: i can open an excel file inside a browser, i mean in the content pane of the browser. I used java language to do this and it works fine, but i am not that sure if the macro can run automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct in assuming that you're asking if a vba macro can be run automatically after opening it from a link on a webpage rendered by a browser, the best way to do that is to set code to run automatically whenever the workbook linked in the webpage is opened.

To have a macro run when a workbook is opened double click the "ThisWorkbook" object in the vba project explorer of the workbook that has your code and add these lines of code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Module1.hello 'Change this line to start your code
End Sub
```

This automatically executes the sub "hello" in Module1 of the workbook.

Note that the user has to have Macros Enabled in their Trust Center Settings for anything to run.

Also note that depending on their browser and where the actual link points to the workbook file might have to be downloaded first and then opened from the download location for the macro to run.